# Инкрементировать числа в файле

Tags: c++, c

Добрый день благородные доны. Есть бинарный файл на 10 мб, забитый единицами. Мне нужно инкрементировать единицы на 1, что бы вместо единиц были двойки. Как это сделать? Желательно с кодом. На с или с++ не принципиально. Будьте добры помогите.

Comment: Там только единицы? Или надо выбрать единицы, заменить двойками, остальное оставить как есть? Или... Понимаете, без точного ТЗ результат - ХЗ...

Comment: да там только единицы

Comment: Своим комментарием вы ничего не прояснили. Какой тип данных используется для хранения чисел? `int`, `uint8_t`, `double` или какой-нибудь другой? Или под единицами вы подразумеваете последовательность байт, каждый из которых хранит ASCII-код символа `1`? Удалите старый файл, забитый единицами и создайте новый, забитый двойками.

Comment: Тогда проще всего создать файл, забитый двойками. `for(int j = 2, i = сколько_надо; i-->0;) outfile.write((char*)&j,sizeof(j));` - что-то типа этого...

Comment: да проще, но нет, надо именно инкрементировать

Comment: 10 Мбайт для сейчас - немного. Считываете все одним блоком в память, инкрементируете, и потом записываете поверх одним же блоком.

Comment: и как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Может вам так подойдет:

```cpp
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char ch;
    fstream data("FILE.bin", ios::in | ios::out); 
    while (data.get(ch)) {              
        data.seekg(-1, ios_base::cur);
        data.put(++ch);
    }
    data.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void incrementArray(int arr[])
{

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10485760; i++)
        arr[i]++;

}

void Read()

{
   
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("FILE.bin", "r+b");
    int ch[10485760];
    fread(ch, 1, sizeof(ch), fp);
  
    incrementArray(ch);
    
    fwrite(ch, 1, sizeof(ch), fp);
    
   
    fclose(fp);
   
}
```

Пробую не выходит, остаются старые значения

Comment: не пишет потому, что  fp после прочтения указывает на конец файла.

Comment: не дороговато по памяти? и вы 2 раза бегаете по одним и тем же данным)